# How php developers choose default constants values?

Tags: php, constants

By using [get_defined_constants](http://www.php.net/get_defined_constants) function from php, I can see all the defined constants by system and myself.

**Example:**

```
<?php

define("MY_CONSTANT", 1);
print_r(get_defined_constants(true));

?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [Core] => Array
        (
            [E_ERROR] => 1
            [E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR] => 4096
            [E_WARNING] => 2
            [E_PARSE] => 4
            [E_NOTICE] => 8
            [E_STRICT] => 2048
            [E_DEPRECATED] => 8192
            [E_CORE_ERROR] => 16
            [E_CORE_WARNING] => 32
            [E_COMPILE_ERROR] => 64
            [E_COMPILE_WARNING] => 128
            [E_USER_ERROR] => 256
            [E_USER_WARNING] => 512
            [E_USER_NOTICE] => 1024
            [E_USER_DEPRECATED] => 16384
            [E_ALL] => 30719
            [DEBUG_BACKTRACE_PROVIDE_OBJECT] => 1
            [DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS] => 2
....
```

**Question:** How did they come up with the integer value to some constants? For example `E_ALL` has a value of `30719`. Why `30719` and not a random number?

Comment: Because `E_ALL` is a effectively a [mask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_%28computing%29). Its decimal value is totally meaningless; what's important is the value of each bit by itself. See http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php

Comment: Those are bitmask values - if you notice, they're all powers of 2 (except for E_ALL, which is all bits 1+2+4+8+16+32... except E_STRICT); there's nothing random about them

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This all comes down to binary:

```
[E_ERROR] => 1                 //000000000000001
[E_WARNING] => 2               //000000000000010
[E_PARSE] => 4                 //000000000000100
[E_NOTICE] => 8                //000000000001000
[E_CORE_ERROR] => 16           //000000000010000
[E_CORE_WARNING] => 32         //000000000100000
[E_COMPILE_ERROR] => 64        //000000001000000
[E_COMPILE_WARNING] => 128     //000000010000000
[E_USER_ERROR] => 256          //000000100000000
[E_USER_WARNING] => 512        //000001000000000
[E_USER_NOTICE] => 1024        //000010000000000
[E_STRICT] => 2048             //000100000000000
[E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR] => 4096  //001000000000000
[E_DEPRECATED] => 8192         //010000000000000
[E_USER_DEPRECATED] => 16384   //100000000000000
[E_ALL] => 30719               //111011111111111 (everything but E_STRICT)
```

If you'd want E_ERROR and E_USER_ERROR, you'd perform a bitwise `OR` statement:

```
define("E_ERROR_ALL", E_ERROR | E_USER_ERROR);
```

This is the same as the following

```
000000000000001 //E_ERROR
000000100000000 //E_USER_ERROR
------|-------| 
000000100000001 //Our custom E_ERROR_ALL
```

as `OR` is super simple:

```
0 - 0 = 0
0 - 1 = 1
1 - 0 = 1
1 - 1 = 1
```

When checking, we can simply use a bitwise `AND` operation, and if the result is more than 0 then that bit is included:

```
<?php
    $errorCode = E_PARSE | E_CORE_ERROR;

    if (($errorCode & E_PARSE) > 0) {
        echo "Error code includes E_PARSE" . PHP_EOL;
    }

    if (($errorCode & E_NOTICE) > 0) {
        echo "Error code includes E_NOTICE" . PHP_EOL;
    }

    if (($errorCode & E_CORE_ERROR) > 0) {
        echo "Error code includes E_CORE_ERROR" . PHP_EOL;
    }
?>
```

Will output

```
Error code includes E_PARSE
Error code includes E_CORE_ERROR
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/jat61Wfi)

The reason this works is because `AND` uses the following logic:

```
0 - 0 = 0
0 - 1 = 0
1 - 0 = 0
1 - 1 = 1
```

Therefore, if we check our custom error code (`10100`) against `E_CORE_ERROR` (`10000`), we get the following operation:

```
    10100
AND 10000
    |----
    10000 = 16 (therefore larger than 0)
```

but if we check with `E_NOTICE` (`01000`), the following operation is performed:

```
    10100
AND 01000
    -----
    00000 = 0 (No match)
```

Comment: @Kirka121 It's an amazing thing to use in your own projects as well (I use it all the time when parsing simple boolean options, as they're very easy to chain.)

Comment: Now I understand it. Thank you!